# How to perform gradient descent in this situation?

Tags: r, gradient-descent

Let's suppose I have *p* predictor variables. For those predictors, there exists a weight vector *w* of length *p* that, if multiplied by the predictors, will minimize an error function. This is not any different than what linear regression performs when the error metric is RMSE. The problem is that I am not using RMSE to determine performance. Instead, I must multiply my weights by my predictors, then plug them into a complex function that takes .5 seconds to compute, and only then do I know if my error improved or worsened.

Pseudo R Code:

```
vec=rnorm(150,0,1)
p=matrix(unlist(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/15))),ncol=10)
response=rnorm(15,0,1)
w=rnorm(15,0,1)

for(i in 1:500){
  #multiply predictors by weights to get predictions
  preds=colSums(t(p)*w)

  #complex error function that takes .5 seconds, e.g.:
  #this isn't the true error function, just an example:
  preds=ifelse(preds>1,preds,ifelse(preds<=1&preds>0,0,-1)) 
  error=mean(abs(response-preds))

  #update weight vector w to move in the most optimal pattern to minimize error
  w= ???
}
```

How to update *w* in the most efficient manner?

Comment: The answer depends on your "complex function."  This problem is encountered--and successfully solved--all the time, but the "most efficient" solutions depend on details of the objective function.  Simply put, if we don't have those details, you are asking for a general course on optimization, which is a vast subject and too broad in scope to be treated here.

Comment: My complex function is extremely complex, and although it doesn't take long to compute, there is no manner in which to apply the normal gradient descent tricks to it. Because of that, I left its details out.

Comment: Right: but what the theory of optimization teaches us is that certain *characteristics* of an objective function and its domain are important.  These include their possible differentiability, continuity, convexity, pseudoconvexity, boundedness, and so on.  If you don't know any of these characteristics then you have little hope, so at a minimum you should attempt to find them out and report them to us.

Comment: If your "complex", which I will interpret to mean, complicated, function is automatically differentiable ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation ), or what amounts to about the same thing (other than being able to compute an entire gradient at once via reverse mode of automatic differentiation), derivatives are evaluable using complex-step differentiation ( http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~maury/paps/NUM_CompDiff.pdf ), you might be in good shape to use gradient-based optimization methods. But also agree with what @whuber wrote.

Answer (score -1):

So, because this "error function" involves methods such that there are no derivatives or other tricks that make gradient descent algorithms useful. I ended up implementing a "brute force" method to work this problem. Basically, if gradient descent meanders its way down the error surface, this method does a crude survey of the entire error surface, and reports back which spots (weights) are low (good weights) and which spots are high.

Original pseudo code modified:

```
#sample data
vec=rnorm(150,0,1)
p=matrix(unlist(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/15))),ncol=10)
response=rnorm(15,0,1)

#create survey weight matrix
set.seed(11)
vec=runif(15*500,-1,1)
w1=matrix(unlist(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/15))),ncol=500)
for(i in 1:ncol(w1)){w1[,i]=w1[,i]/sum(w1[,i])}

#survey loop
for(i in 1:500){
  #multiply predictors by weights to get predictions
  w=w1[,i]
  preds=colSums(t(p)*w)

  #complex error function that takes .5 seconds, e.g.:
  #this isn't the true error function, just an example:
  preds=ifelse(preds>1,preds,ifelse(preds<=1&preds>0,0,-1)) 
  error[i]=mean(abs(response-preds))

}
```

I hope this can help anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation. Additionally, you could run this loop multiple times, each time selecting the best weights from the previous round, and shrinking the bounds of the random uniform distribution used for the survey weights. This would effectively shrink the area that you are surveying to an area you know is good, in hopes of getting closer to the minimum.

Comment: **If** your function really does not have derivatives (which I am not convinced is the case yet), you've still got plenty of better options. For example, you could use the Nelder-Mead algorithm (available in R's `optim` function).